# Google Cloud Endpoints Sample for Go using gRPC response service fail

Tags: go, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am new using cloud platform. I trying to deploy a service using go and grpc. I found this tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started-grpc and everything was complete successful until I have to call the service.

In the moment that I use the client to call the service I get this error:

`could not greet: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 35.199.74.154:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond.`

I would like to know if someone can help me with that problem.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you in a meaningful way. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to ask a question with a minimal and reproducible example

Comment: Thank you Eli for you reply. I just follow this tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started-grpc. On it there are all information to reproduce step by step the example.